# Merging three regex patterns used for text cleaning to improve efficiency

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Given a text I want to make some modifications:

1. replace uppercase chars at the beginning of a sentence.
2. remove chars like `’` or `'` (without adding whitespace)
3. remove unwanted chars for example `³` or `?` `,` `!` `.` (and replace with whitespace)

```
def multiple_replace(text):
    # first sub so words like can't will change to cant and not can t
    first_strip=re.sub("[’']",'',text) 
    def cap(match):
        return (match.group().lower())

    p = re.compile(r'((?<=[\.\?!]\s)(\w+)|(^\w+))')
    #second sub to change all words that begin a sentence to lowercase
    second_strip = p.sub(cap,first_strip) 
    # third_strip is to remove all . from text unless they are used in decimal numbers
    third_strip= re.sub(r'(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)','',second_strip)
    # fourth strip to remove unexpected char that might be in text for example !,?³ and replace with whitespace
    forth_strip=re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9@#_$&%]+',' ', third_strip)
    return forth_strip
```

I am  wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it? Because I am  going over the text 4 times just so it can be in the right format for me to parse. This seems a lot especially if there are millions of documents. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Nothing obvious comes to mind, but it may be an XY problem since you mention you're trying to "parse" something. If you show a representative snippet of the input along with the final output you want and an explanation of the transformation you're trying to achieve, there may be a better way that avoids this particular approach entirely.

Comment: It's possible that the time to parse will outweigh the time to 'clean' the text, in which case there's not much point in making the cleaning more efficient. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.” -Knuth

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of an alternation to match either an uppercase char A-Z at the start of the string, or after `.` `?` or `!` followed by a whitespace char.

I think you can also add a `.` to the negated character class `[^A-Za-z0-9@#_$&%.]+` to not remove the dot for a decimal value and change the order of operations to use `cap` first before removing any dots.

```
import re

def cap(match):
    return match.group().lower()


p = re.compile(r'(?<=[.?!]\s)[A-Z]|^[A-Z]', re.M)

text = "A test here. this `` (*)is. Test, but keep 1.2"
first_strip = p.sub(cap, text)
second_strip = re.sub(r"[`']+|(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)", '', first_strip)
third_strip = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9@#_$&%.]+', ' ', second_strip)
print(third_strip)
```

Output

```
a test here this is test but keep 1.2
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/KSwiKL)

---

You could also use a lambda with all 3 patterns and 2 capturing groups checking the group values in the callback, but I think that would not benefit the readability or making it easier to change or test.

```
import re

p = re.compile(r"(?:((?<=[.?!]\s)[A-Z]|^[A-Z])|[`']+|((?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d))|[^A-Za-z0-9@#_$&%.]+)", re.M)
text = "A test here. this `` (*)is. Test, but keep 1.2"
result = re.sub(p, lambda x: x.group(1).lower() if x.group(1) else ('' if x.group(2) else ' '), text)

print(result)
```

Output

```
a test here this is test but keep 1.2
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/U8qrQU)

Comment: what does re.M do? anyway with this code if my string would contain "test y’all Towson took away'' then it would split  y’all  to y all and so when i split the string its two different tokens, which is why i need it to be yall

Comment: It means Multiline, there is an anchor `^` in the pattern.